# how to change icon in XNA

Tags: windows, xna, icons

I built a game, and I wanted to change the icon (this is a windows game.) I tried removing the Game.ico that it came with and put in another , but now it just showed the standard exe file icon. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating an appropriate .ico file to replace the Game.ico file with in your Content project? Are you calling it Game.ico or are you using a new name?

Comment: Yes it is an .ico file, and I did name it Game.ico

Comment: How did you create it or what did you use to edit it? Did you make a 32 bit .ico file? If you simply just edit the original Game.ico file included by default in new Windows Game Projects, do your edits work?

Comment: I used http://www.xiconeditor.com/ and yes it is 32 by 32.

Comment: now i reset it to the old one but it still shows the exe icon

Comment: If you right-click on your project in Visual Studio and got to Properties then select "Application" from the list on the left. What does it say in the Resources section for your Icon file. Is the Game.ico file seleced? If not browse out and select it via the browse.

Comment: Thanks I just pointed to the .ico in it and it worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When changing the .ico file, right-click on your project in Visual Studio and go to Properties. Select "Application" form the list on the left. In the "Resources" section browse to the icon file that you wish to use for your game.

Note that the .ico file is only used by XNA on Windows game projects and is ignored for Xbox 360 and Windows Phone 7 games. Also note that it's often easier to edit the existing Game.ico file and make your changes to that file when possible (easier because it's already linked and is in the correct format).